# How to set up a Join according to a value for one Column?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server query:

```
SELECT tblRoom.ID, tblRoom.RoomType, tblActivity.Time , tblActivity.Day
FROM tblRoom , tblActivity
Where tblRoom.RoomType Like 'CO' 
Where tblRoom.ID=tblActivity.RoomID 
Order by tblRoom.ID
```

I want to Join the Day and Time from tblActivity but only for Responsibility which is = to 'CO' available in tblRoom

The error message is :

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'.
```

Comment: well, for starters you are using `WHERE` twice, you should replace one with an `AND`. (and, as a good habit, please use an explicit join instead of the old implicit one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use WHERE twice, also, please consider use JOIN

```
SELECT tblRoom.ID, tblRoom.RoomType, tblActivity.Time , tblActivity.Day
FROM tblActivity
INNER JOIN tblRoom 
  ON tblRoom.RoomType ='CO' --Only display Time and Day for Roomtype CO 
  AND tblRoom.ID=tblActivity.RoomID 
Order by tblRoom.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT r.ID, r.RoomType, a.Time , a.Day
FROM tblRoom r join tblActivity a
on r.ID=a.RoomID 
Where r.RoomType Like 'CO' 
Order by r.ID
```